# Comparing 2 objects from different classes java

Tags: java, string, class, object

Is it possible to compare 2 object from 2 different classes.

lets say i have an vector which adds all the objects from class A. i want to compare some string to the elements of the vector.

Example:

```
if(string.equals(vector.get(i)))
```

is this possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you have a more specific question that this isn't working as you expect?

Comment: Can you be more specific so as to what do you want to compare?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can call `equals()`. However, any reasonable implementation of `SomeClass.equals()` would return `false` if the argument is of a different class (other than perhaps a subclass).

If `string` is an instance of `java.lang.String`, this behaviour is [specifically guaranteed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not `null` and **is a `String` object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Comment: yes i have a different class and it returns false, how can i fix it

Comment: @KarishKarish: Define "fix".

Comment: ok i have class A and class B. class a has a constructor that takes a string. class B contain vector which add all the elements from Class A . when i compare vector to a string  get false

Answer (score 1):

Your objects are at least in the class Object, and thus (at least partly) in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Equals method of an object can take any other object. However, it would be up to the implementation to not return true when comparing an apple with an orange

Answer (score 0):

If the list's elements have type other than String it will always return false. From the `String` documentation for method `equals`:

> > Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

This is generally true for the method equals - it will or should return true only in the eventuality that the compared object is of the same class or a subclass of the former.

Comment: the problem that i use a different class and it gives me false when i compare them

Comment: Well, that is expected to happen. But I'm guessing you need to compare the String to some field in the other class. So why don't you just call equals on the other class' field ?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid to write something like;

```
public class MyClass {
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof SomeUnrelatedClass) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it is not advisable, as least *I* would try to avoid it. It would make handling `MyClass` objects a little strange, for example putting them into a hash-based collection.